# Firefox opening word 97-2003 documents with xml file editor

Tags: firefox, microsoft-word, xml

When attempting to open older Word documents in my Firefox browser, they open with the XML editor instead of in word itself. However if I click to Save the file it saves as a word document.

The same file from the same website opens with no issues in IE and Google Chrome. Usually I would just use another browser or the Save As option, but I'm worried that other Firefox users may be having the same problem with my web app, so I just wanted to double check.

Comment: Try to see if you have an entry for the file format in Options->Application.

Comment: There isn't no, should there be if I have Word installed?

Comment: I just guessed that there might have been. That's how they recommend you to change these things http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions